# Encryption,decryption using Crypto

Tags: node.js, cryptography, base64

I am using `Crypto` to encrypt and decrypt my data.
So, lets say I have encryption key is `key=b3ecb60efb7145bfb87e077c27e7c207` and I have data `app_t={"referenceId":"324hweu23b23"}` to encrypt.

Now, first of all I am encoding data to `base64` and then ecnrypting with the help of key. below is my code:

```
function encDatafn(data,key){
 var base64_data=new Buffer(data).toString("base64");
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('AES-256-ECB', key); 
            var encdata = cipher.update(base64_data,'base64','utf8');
            return encdata+=cipher.final('utf8');
}

var encData=encDatafn(app_t,Key)
console.log(encData);
```

so I am getting encrypted string is `v��dic��0\��[�'�l��i�bp�H�f`;
Now when I am trying to decrypt it so its not working below is decrypt code:

```
function decdatafn(data,key){
            var dec_base64=new Buffer(JSON.stringify(data),"base64").toString();
            var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('AES-256-ECB', key);
            var decDataa = decipher.update(dec_base64,'base64','utf8');
            return decDataa+=decipher.final('utf8');
        }

        var decData=decdatafn(encData,key)
        console.log("decDataaa="+decData);
```

Its showing error that: 
`Error: error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length`

Please let me know whats wrong in this form.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try using `binary` instead of `utf-8` while encrypting? In other words can you please try changing your `return encdata+=cipher.final('utf8');` as `return encdata+=cipher.final('binary');` ??

Comment: Yes I changed to `binary`   now its giving me `��ޭ��x�wۈpz��om�`

Comment: but still decryption not working

Comment: Is the data coming from `MongoDB`?

Comment: No, data is not coming from DB